# Time.timeScale in Unity C# not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, menu, pause

I'm a pretty noob programmer trying to make a simple pause menu for my game. I keep getting this error though:

*Error  3   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object            expressions can be used as a statement*

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class pause : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("escape") && Time.timeScale == 1)
        {
            Time.timeScale == 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `==` checks for equality, and isn't a `assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, or new object expression`.  `=` is an `assignment expression`, and is what you want. Also, for future questions make sure to include all error info, especially which line it occurs on.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting this error is because of this statement:

```
Time.timeScale == 0;
```

You are using the double equals operator which is a logical operator.  This statement is comparing the current value of timescale to 0 and returning the boolean result of the equality comparison. As the error message indicates, boolean expressions by themselves can not be used as statements.

I'm assuming you're trying to set the value of timescale to 0.  If that's the case, change the statement to:

```
Time.timescale = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks! The error has gone but I can still move my character etc after I activate it.